# Plot Graph in C++ using Tex

Tags: c++, tex

I have two arrays x and y and would like to use Tex to output a plot of the data, but my code doesn't appear to output the correct plot. Any help to guide me in this problem is much appreciated.

```cpp
// function for plotting x and y data 
void Plot(double x[], double y[]) {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("Plot.tex", "w");

    // construct the plot
    fprintf(fp, "\\documentclass{standalone}\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\usepackage{pgfplots}\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\begin{document}\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\begin{tikzpicture}\n");
    // add a plot 
    fprintf(fp, "\\begin{axis}[\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\title={Title},\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\xlabel={xlabel},\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\ylabel={ylabel},\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\xmin=%8.4f, xmax=%8.4f,\n", x[0] * .80, x[10] * 1.20);
    fprintf(fp, "\\ymin=%8.4f, ymax=%8.4f,\n", y[0] * .80, y[10] * 1.20);
    fprintf(fp, "\\ymajorgrids=true,\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\grid style=dashed,\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\]\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\addplot gnuplot[id=IV];\n", y);


    // complete the construction 
    fprintf(fp, "\\end{axis}\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\end{tikzpicture}\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\\end{document}\n");
    fclose(fp);

    return;
}
```

The output is:
[image]

My output should be a line plot:

[image]

Comment: Could you describe the exact error in more detail and possibly provide a minimal working code example?

Comment: I've modified my question above

Comment: Is that the complete function? You didn't leave anything out?

Comment: Don't have anything beyond that in the function